# Unable to malloc string in struct

Tags: c, string, struct, malloc

My struct looks like this:

```
struct tree{
    char *name;
    int num_subdirs;
    struct tree **subdirs;
}
```

I am receiving a buffer that contains this entire tree serialized in a buffer. I am trying to deserialize it in this function:

```
struct tree *t;
//buffer is filled, received from somewhere else.
int res = deserialize(t, buf); //call function deserialize

//deserialize function
            //buf = {../,2}{sd,0}{|}{sr,1}{sk,0}{|}{|}
   │406     int dfsDeserialize(struct tree *dt, void *buf, int *q){                                                                                                                       │
   │407         char name[MAXPATHLEN];                                                                                                                                                           │
   │408         char delim[3];                                                                                                                                                                   │
   │409         int len, numsubs, i;                                                                                                                                                             │
                                                                                                                                                        │
   │411         sscanf(buf+(*q),"%3s",delim);                                                                                                                                                    │
   │412         if(!strcmp(delim,"{|}")){                                                                                                                                                        │
   │413             (*q)+=3;                                                                                                                                                                     │
   │414             return 1;                                                                                                                                                                    │
   │415         }                                                                                                                                                                                │
   │416         sscanf((buf + (*q)), "{%[^,],%d}%n", name, &numsubs, &len);                                                                                                                      │                                                                                                                                          │
  >│419         int slen = strlen(name);                                                                                                                                                         │
   │420         dt->name = calloc(slen + 1, 1);                                                                                                                                                  │
   │421         dt->subdirs = malloc(numsubs*sizeof(struct tree *));                                                                                                                      │
   │422         strcpy(dt->name, name);                                                                                                                                                          │
   │423         dt->num_subdirs = numsubs;                                                                                                                                                       │
   │424         (*q)+=len;                                                                                                                                                                       │
   │425         for(i = 0; i< numsubs; i++){                                                                                                                                                     │
   │426             dt->subdirs[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct tree));                                                                                                                         │
   │427             dfsDeserialize(dt->subdirs[i], buf, q);                                                                                                                                      │
   │428         }                                                                                                                                                                                │
   │429         return 0;                                                                                                                                                                        │
   │430     }   

                                                                                                                                                                             │
```

I have tried several different ways of allocating memory for string but it fails every single time! I don't know why is t->name always 0x0. Please help.

Comment: How did you pass `t` to the function `dfsDeserialize`?

Comment: I declared a t and passed it. i.e. struct tree *t;

Comment: Since you've skipped the code that parses the buffer and the code that we can see looks OK, we have to assume that the code you have omitted caused the trouble — or you have some memory problems elsewhere that finally trigger a problem here.  Are you on a platform where you can use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)?  If so, use it.  If not, life is harder.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Buffer seems to be fine, so is parsing. On GDB I can see that name is parsed properly and that I can only not malloc name. For some reason.

Comment: Hmmm; you're recursing in this code, and setting `t` each time, but never updating it in the calling function.  You're leaking memory fast.  And the code that first calls this cannot access anything that you've read.  Also, we can't see if you update `buf`, but if you don't, each recursive call is going to be parsing the same data, so you'll not stop recursing — and will run out of memory.

Comment: @Neo: you probably want to `malloc` the tree first.

Comment: The fact that everything appears normal is normal — when you've got a memory trampling problem, you often can't spot it until too late.

Comment: note that `t` is like a local variable and what it points to after you leave the function will be lost. if you want to permanently change what `t` points to you need to pass the address of `t`

Comment: alt try using strdup instead of calloc/strcpy

Comment: As @JonathanLeffler tells you, you didn't give us the code for `name` extraction. Try to enforce the value for `name`by hand (`strcpy(name,"xxx")`) and observe the results. What is the `slen` value that leads to the problem? etc.

Comment: You aren't setting the entries in `child`.  It's allocated, and initially contains undefined values.  Those undefined values are then passed to `deserialize` where they are ignored, but they are never updated in `child`.  To do so, you either need to pass the address, and have `deserialize` store to it, or else have deserialize return the child address, setting it where it's called.

Comment: @TomKarzes I did not get you. Wouldn't each child be set recursively in subsequent calls?

Comment: No.  Not until you change your code to do so.  Where do you think the entries in `child` are being set?  Nowhere.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Updated the actual code. This is exactly my code minus  dead code.

Comment: Ok, well this code is different from what was posted before.  In this version it looks like `subdirs` is being set.

Comment: But now it looks like the `sizeof` is wrong.  It should be `sizeof(struct tree)`, not `sizeof(struct dirtreenode)`  Or should `tree` in fact be `dirtreenode`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102766/discussion-between-neo-and-tom-karzes).

Comment: You have a buffer overflow.  The size in your format string is `%3s` but the array is only 3 bytes long.  Unfortunately, the `scanf()` functions take the size excluding the null terminator, so you have a one-byte overwrite potential, which can be disastrous.  Increase the size of `delim` to at least 4, or change the format to specify 2 instead of 3.  Whether that's the cause of all your trouble is open to debate, but buffer overflows are never good news.

Comment: Ok, looks like it's changed again.  In the future, please don't post code that varies so wildly from what you're debugging.  The time people could have spent debugging your code has instead been spent identifying mistakes that were made posting it.

Comment: @TomKarzes Totally my fault. I apologize.

Comment: It looks like `delim` has been declared too small.  You need to add 1 for the terminating null byte of the string.  As it stands, `sscanf` is writing past the end of it.

Comment: @TomKarzes That definitely is a bug. I am trying with the correction in my code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the culprit is this

```
t = malloc(sizeof(sizeof tree));
```

You probably meant

```
t = malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
```

you can also use the more handier strdup to copy a string on the heap

```
t->name = strdup(name);
```

Comment: I think the same. It looks like a bug.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan yes, a typo

Comment: That's definitely a bug, but not the only one.

Comment: @TomKarzes I've updated representational code to the actual code I am using.

Answer (score 0):

C uses "pass by value".  When you pass an argument to a function, the function receives a copy of the argument. So when you have:

```
struct tree *t;
int res = deserialize(t, buf); //call function deserialize
```

nothing that the function does can affect `t`. The function gets a copy of the current value of `t`.  (Since `t` is uninitialized, this may cause undefined behaviour).

Instead you need to tell the function where `t` is found in memory:

```
int res = deserialize(&t, buf);
```

and the function might look like:

```
int deserialize(struct tree **p_t, void *buf)
{
    struct tree *t = malloc(sizeof *t);
    // ... set up t as before

    // tell the caller about what we did
    *p_t = t;
}
```

---

An alternative approach would be to leave `deserialize` as it is but remove the `malloc` entirely; and require that the caller allocates space before calling the function. This is more flexible as then the caller can choose to use automatic allocation or dynamic allocation.

Comment: Okay, but what about the children node in consequtive calls? I would need to malloc them, right?

Comment: NOTE: this answer was written before the latest edit, in which memory is never allocated at any stage

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought for clarity it would be better to use the actual code.

Comment: @Neo you mean `subdirs`? Hard to say since the existing code is incomplete.

Comment: Yes. Subdirs. They would have to be malloced right?

Comment: My advice would be to not mix up memory management code with your serialization logic. Instead make a function which allocates all the required memory.  Also it's unclear whether you need individual mallocs for each subdir, instead of mallocing a block

Comment: And how would I do that? I would need to parse the string and find exact number of dir and subdirs to add. Right?

Comment: Gather all the information you need to allocate, and then call a function to do the allocation.  Ideally this function would return the pointer that it allocated (avoiding the need to use pass-by-pointer as I described in my answer)